# Hibernate List<String> Java Persistence 1.0

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, jpa-1.0

I seem to have problems with mapping a List in *Hibernate*. In our project there is a class `Profile`, it contains a `List<String>`.

Is `List<String>` mappable by *Hibernate* using annotations, using *Java Persistence 1.0* (NO `ElementCollection`!)? (annotations like `@Entity`)

I know that *Java Persistence 2.0* consists of `ElementCollection`, but in our project we have only *Java Persistence 1.0*.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like that in JPA 1. You have to fallback to Hibernate specific annotation and use [CollectionOfElements](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionOfElements.html) instead:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements 
List<String> myElements;
```